# Delete selected row in datagrid and also in database?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid

I want to delete from database when i select a row in datagridview.
I tried 2 different methods.
With this method i can delete only a few rows.

```
cmd.CommandText = "delete from dbo.Scenarist  where idScenarist=@idScenarist";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idScenarist", dataGridScenarist.SelectedIndex));
```

I tried also with SelectedRows, but i have this error:

> 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for
>   'SelectedRow' and no extension method 'SelectedRow' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is a WPF App and i can't use DataGridView.Only DataGrid.
 Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to use `DataGridView` here. It provides access to `SelectedRows` which is a collection of `DataGridViewRow`s. Loop through that collection and update your `@idScenarist` parameter with the value from the column containing the corresponding id, and execute the delete command object in each loop.

Here is a basic example:

```
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from dbo.Scenarist  where idScenarist=@idScenarist";
        SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@idScenarist", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridScenarist.SelectedRows)
        {
            parm.Value = row.Cells["idScenarist"].Value;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: Or better still use the "in" syntax and do it one call.

Comment: For that, you would have to do string concatenation for each parameter and add a parameter object for each value. Definitely doable, and depending upon your application, might be a better approach. My preference is to stay away from dynamically building a SQL query when you are dealing with an unknown maximum.

Comment: if you use linq `var result = String.Join(",", rows.select(r => r.id.ToString()));` you can do it one go, but a good point about not knowing the size of the delete set.

Comment: I can't use DataGridView because is a WPF App!

Comment: I can look at some alternative methods of doing this, but I need some more information from you. Do you have your `DataGrid` bound to something already that could be used as a collection of items to loop through?

Comment: @RoxanaCosconea I just don't think there is going to be a way to do this. I mean, it could be possible to write your own implementation of a custom `DataGridView` control, but you shouldn't have to. There is this article, which I am currently looking over and may give it a try: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nagasatish/2007/08/01/datagridview-in-a-wpf-application/ if you want to give it a go yourself too. I will keep poking around in the meantime to see what I can find, if anything. It seems really ridiculous that there is no simple data grid that exposes a simple selected row collection.

Comment: I did it!      object item = dataGridScenarist.SelectedItem;
               string ID = (dataGridScenarist.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;

Comment: The drawback to that, though, is that it gets all cells, horizontal and vertical, correct? So you need to loop through that whole collection and determine if the cell contains the correct "id" for using in your `delete` statement, correct? I mean, it should be a workable solution, but it still seems like there should be a better one. =)